# Post Size Limit

Tags: posts

I am in the process of writing a very long post -- currently 8,500 words and around 40 images, with more to come -- and, all of a sudden, the preview doesn't work: It just shows empty content, with the header loading correctly. The symptoms are the same as described on [this page](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/sudden-empty-blank-page-for-large-posts-with-wordpress/), however I am not using any shortcodes. (Although, maybe that wouldn't matter: If the problem is with PHP's RegExp, then whether there are shortcodes or not, length will still be an issue.)

Unfortunately, this is on a managed server, so I have no way of changing the PHP.ini file. As such, what are my options? If this is the likely cause, presumably the only thing I can do is split my post into several. Any other ideas?... Thanks :)

EDIT: Using WP 3.2.1

Comment: Have you tried disabling plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following snippet, you'll see all filters attached to the title, content & excerpt (from /wp-includes/default-filters.php). Try to remove in a first try only stuff like capital P dangit, smilies and such and if this doesn't work, remove the more critical stuff. I'd only do this until the post saves and then move stuff out or wrap it into a `if ( is_single( $post->ID ) )` statement to not trigger it elsewhere.

```
foreach ( array( 'the_content', 'the_title' ) as $filter )
    remove_filter( $filter, 'capital_P_dangit', 11 );

// Display filters
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize'   );
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'convert_chars' );
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'trim'          );

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'wptexturize'      );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'convert_smilies'  );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'convert_chars'    );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'wpautop'          );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'shortcode_unautop');
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );
```

Comment: Thank you :) I've accepted your answer, as it will almost certainly prove useful elsewhere; but I actually managed to solve this myself, by accident... My post linked to an external file, in the gallery, which was still within my domain but a restricted filetype. I toggled this to an accepted type, removed the link and uploaded the file within the gallery: Now the post appears correctly, in its entirety!?

Comment: First step: Deactivate Plugins, Second: Switch to default theme. If nothing works: Guess. Hard to trace "bug". Glad you found it :)